# How to connect OpenJUMP to PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgis, spatial, postgresql-10

I Installed PostgreSQL 10 on a CentOS 7 machine, then installed its GIS extension, created a database and enabled the spatial extension on it, all is working as expected, now I wanted to use OpenJUMP to visualize the data.

I downloaded `OpenJUMP-Installer-1.13-r5792-CORE.jar` from the OpenJUMP page, I have previously downloaded Java and set up the JAVA_HOME env variable.

I proceed to the installation by executing

```
sudo java -jar OpenJUMP-Installer-1.13-r5792-CORE.jar
```

It was installed under `/opt/OpenJUMP` finally I executed

```
/opt/OpenJUMP/bin/oj_linux.sh &
```

and it opened, then I tried to establish a connection with my PostgreSQL database, I chose

```
File -> Run Datastore Query -> Add -> PostGIS
```

But it appears like this, I cannot enter the connection details on the boxes

[image: OpenJUMP connection issues]

I searched for possible causes but I cannot find something, in theory, it should work out of the box, I found that I might need to add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver
but I'm not sure if this is true or how is it done.

Do I have to do something else to my PostgreSQL database to allow OpenJUMP connections?

Do I have to do a special configuration to OpenJUMP to enable those boxes?

Comment: You should use a Postgresql driver, I've never heard of a Postgis driver. You would be accessing Postgis via Postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug on the GUI, I just had to resize the dialog and the `jTextFields` were fixed
[image: Fix]

Regarding the drivers, there is no need to add any extra jar in order to connect to PostgreSQL and PostGIS, hope this help someone